# Why is dictionary in object not different from the other?

Tags: python, object

I have the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6

class container(object):
    name = 'container'
    configuration = {'var1': 'var1',
                     'var2': 'var2'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container1 = container()
    container2 = container()
    container2.name = 'container2'
    container2.configuration['var2'] = 'newvar2'

    print container1.name
    print container1.configuration['var2']
```

I expect this to print 'container' and 'var2', but for the latter it prints 'newvar2' instead

Why does the configuration variable point to the same dictionary for both objects? How can I fix this?

Most answers are already explaining that name and configuration are class variables. Why does the change of container2.name not influence container1.name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `configuration` is a class variable and not an instance variable. Fixing this should fix your problem.

```
class container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'container'

        self.configuration = {'var1': 'var1',
                             'var2': 'var2'}
```

What's going on here is that `configuration` ends up living in `containter.__dict__` instead of in the dictionaries of its instances when you make it a class variable.  This means that `c.configuration` is just accessing `container.__dict__['configuration']` for all instances `c`.

For any class variable, an assignment of the form `c.foo = x`, creates an entry for `foo` in `c.__dict__` which shadows its entry in `container.__dict__`. So a lookup will return that first. If you delete it, then a lookup will go back to retrieving the class instance. You could do

```
c = container()
c.configuration = x
```

and then `c.configuration` would be whatever `x` was. But inserting a key isn't an assignment, it's a method call on an existing object accessed through an existing binding.

You could get away with making `name` a class variable but if you want it to change from one instance to another then it should be an instance variable (unless you want a class wide default of course).

so:

1. An assignment (using `=`, `setattr` or directly inserting in `__dict__`) on an instance will shadow a class variable. The class variable is still there.
2. A lookup (calling a method, accessing the value) on an instance will grab an instance attribute if it exists and a class variable otherwise.

Comment: Why is `name` not a class variable then? Wouldn't I expect that one to change too?

Answer (score 3):

Because `name` and `configuration` are class or static members of the container class and they are shared for all the instances of container. Use self.name, self.configuration for instance variables:

```
class container(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.name = "container"
      self.configuration = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.name = 'container'
self.configuration = {'var1': 'var1',
                      'var2': 'var2'}
```

In **init**() if they are the class variables.